# Why does this method for reading in a value from a file in C causes a segfault?

Tags: c, linux, file

**The background for my problem**

I am presently writing a video game in C as a personal project. Due to the increasing number of hard-coded values, it was becoming impractical to store them directly inside the source code. Instead, it was decided that the values should be stored in files and then be dynamically read in, when relevant. Several options were available for this, but all of them were too tedious to set up and overkill for the desired usage. Therefore, I decided to write my own implementation of a file reader that returns values stored in files.

**Initial approach to the solution**

To make my code as generalizeable as possible, it was decided that the strategy i.e function that reads the file and returns the value, should first of all, return a *void pointer*, because it can store arbitrary values. The way that you then retrieved a value from a specific file, was that you would provide an argument specifying the desired type of the return value e.g by using an enum. The function would then based on the enum, store the value as the corresponding data type in the void pointer and it would be your responsibility to cast the returned void pointer to the correct type.

**Expected file format**

The files that the code should read, would be simple text files. The files in question, would consist of lines of variable names with a value assigned to them. Here is an example of how a file for my project would look like.

```
name=main_character
money=1000
damage_multiplier=1.2
```

So for example, the variable name would have the char* value of "main_character", the variable money would have the int value of 1000 and damage_multiplier, the float value of 1.2

**Current code**

Obviously including the entire code repository of my game won't be useful, so instead I have attempted to the best of my abilities to provide a minimum reproducible example.

We define the enum Return_Type that we pass as an argument to the function in order to retrieve a variable as a specific type

```
typedef enum{integer, string, floating,struct_limb,struct_attributes}Return_Type;
```

So if we want to return a variable as an integer, we pass the value integer to the method

The file i am presently trying to read from is a file that represents a creature struct. Its contents looks like this.

```
species=0
name=Short-faced bear
representation=a
id=0
limb_count=7
limbs=[[0,0,100,100],[1,0,100,100],[2,0,100,100],[2,0,100,100],[3,0,100,100],[3,0,100,100],[4,0,100,100]]
weight=900
height=3.4
attributes=[12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12]
max_health=100
max_carry=100
preferred_attack_type=1
```

The method used to read the file is this function

```
void *ir_readin_data(char *file_path, char *variable, Return_Type expected_type){
void *value;
FILE *fp = fopen(file_path, "r");
char * line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
while((getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1){
  char *variable_pointer = strstr(line, variable);
  if(variable_pointer != NULL){
    char *value_as_str = strtok(strchr(line, '=')+1, "\n");
   if(expected_type == integer){
    /*Deprecated, but still used for sake of ease, strtol doesn't                                                                         
     work either */
    int value_as_integer = atoi(value_as_str);
    value = &value_as_integer;
    fclose(fp);
    return value;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

For sake of readability, I have reduced the function to only consider the case when we want to retrieve the variable as an integer.

For the minimum reproducible example, i am trying to read the variable species from the file and i want it to be retrieved as an integer

```
*(int *)ir_readin_data(creature_file_path,"species", integer);
```

I would have gone on to demonstrate all the different approaches I have tried to remedy the problem, but I feel that this question is already dragging on quite a bit. I have tried approaches like passing a void pointer as an argument and store the value in that instead, I have tried to return the value as a char pointer, return the value in a union and so on. None of the approaches work. I feel like there is some subtlety in  reading files that I haven't caught up on yet. Can you pinpoint me as to what the error is?

**Edit:solution**

Thanks to David Ranieri for the solution. The problem was that in my example, I stored local variables in the void pointer, that cease to persist at the end of the function call. The solution I have opted for, is to use pointer variables instead. Akin to the minimal reproducible example, here is the basic example of how I worked this into my solution, in the hope that other people facing similar issues find it useful.

```
void *ir_readin_data(char *file_path, char *variable, Return_Type expected_type){
void *value;
FILE *fp = fopen(file_path, "r");
char * line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
while((getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1){
  char *variable_pointer = strstr(line, variable);
  if(variable_pointer != NULL){
    char *value_as_str = strtok(strchr(line, '=')+1, "\n");
    if(expected_type == integer){
      /*Deprecated, but still used for sake of ease, strtol   doesn't                                                                         
     work either */
      int value_as_integer = atoi(value_as_str);
      int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
      /*This approach works */
      *(ptr) = value_as_integer;
      value = ptr;
      fclose(fp);
      return value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `return value;` --> You are returning the address of a local variable whose lifetime ends when the function exits.

Comment: Thanks for help! I get the whole jazz about local variables, variables that are found on the stack vs variables found on the heap, but i thought that storing them in the void pointer would be sufficient to make them persist. I guess not. So my new approach will be that i store malloc'd values in the void pointer, instead of the locally computed variables in the function call.

Comment: _So my new approach will be that i store malloc'd values in the void pointer_ - yes, that's a good approach, also, remember to `free` the result from `getline` in order to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: *The variable name would have the `char*` value of "main_character"* -- This statement indicates a fundamental confusion: A `char *` cannot *have* a string value; it can only *point at* a string value which must exist in a char array somewhere.  The char array is a separate object from the pointer variable and has its own lifetime that needs to be managed,

Comment: My suggestion is that you emulate *pass by reference*, by passing a pointer to the variable you need to set, and have the `ir_readin_data` function return a success/failure status. Then there's no need to dynamically allocate anything, at least not for the plain `int` case.

Comment: And why is `strol` not working? It should work *better* than `atoi`, and with validation.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. Some Programmer dude, i have changed it so that I now use pass by reference to store the result directly in the variables in question. As why strtol didn't work, see my edit. I know it is preferred to use strtol since it does more error handling, but i was just less familiar with it and its technicalities.

Comment: As to Chris Dodd's remark on "strings" in C - I am aware that C doesn't have Strings in the way other programming languages do. I just named it that way mostly because it was my own little project i never intended other people to look at and "in the real world" it is incorrect practice to refer to char pointers as strings.